# How can a ApiController Post return a response?

Tags: http-post, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-apicontroller

I have a Post method in an ApiController that accepts json using the [FromBody] and  then transforms/appends to it. I need the response from the http POST to return that json back to the javascript client that is calling it. The Post method in the ApiController is a void. How can I return string/json to the client?

Comment: Change the method's return type from `void` to `string`?  (Or to whatever type you want to return.)

Comment: Yes... (facepalm). Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results to read about all the options. If you use `IHttpActionResult`, `ApiController` has some neat helper methods for return stuff and setting different status codes. e.g. base.Ok(object), base.BadRequest(), etc.